# Best format for GDAL to ESRI

Tags: python, gdal, arcgis-10.2

I'm trying to create a 30 meter, Int16 raster covering the entire continental US using Python/GDAL. This raster will ultimately be used to do raster algebra in ArcMap by downstream users.

Ordinarily I would use GTiff for this, but I'm getting the error message

```
ERROR 6: A 141014 pixels x 145929 lines x 1 bands Int16 image would be larger than 4GB but this is the largest size a TIFF can be, and BigTIFF is unavailable.  Creation failed.
```

So my question is twofold: (1) is BigTIFF the best format for creating a Arc-compatible raster, and (2) if so, how do I make it available?

Comment: Are you compressing it?

Comment: (2) You must have GDAL that is compiled with such libtiff library that supports BigTIFF.

Comment: I just got GDAL working with BigTiff but apparently the raster will be too large to fit on my hard drive.  Is there a compressed format that is compatible with ArcGIS?